# Query Dates and return biweekly temperature avg

Tags: sql, average

Not sure how to approach this one.. I need to take a ton of temperature data.. and average them at biweekly intervals.. I've played  with pivotchart and can only return weekly avg's..

```
Table:TempData

SITE  Date  Temperature_C
JON   6/4/2001 28
JON   6/4/2001 29
JON   6/4/2001 26
JON   6/5/2001 24
JON   6/5/2001 27
```

etc..

I could create a query that breaks all the dates into a specific ID.. like 1-100 with each value representing a 2 week avg from 6/4/2001 - whatever 200 weeks later is. Then work with Pivot chart that way.. Of course I would have to AVG an vast number of dates (many with different amounts of recorded values.. somes days there are 4 records.. some there are 40). Any code I could use to search a continuous series based on a date.. Datesub()? I'm at a loss.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to take the number of days since some start date and divide by 14.  Here is an example using SQL Server syntax:

```
select datediff(day, cast('2012-01-01' as date), [date])/14 as weeknumber,
       min([date]) as weekstart,
       max([date]) as weekend,
       avg(Temperature_C*1.0) as avg_temp
from TempData
group by datediff(day, cast('2012-01-01' as date), [date])/14 
order by 1
```

In other databases, the logic would be similar, but the specific functions would differ.

By the way, 1/1/2012 was a Sunday, so this would have the week being Sunday - Saturday (which is typically reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT anyColumn, …, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateColumn) / 2 * 2 , 0) as biweekly, avg(temperature)
FROM table
WHERE condition
GROUP BY anyColumn, …, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateColumn) / 2 * 2 , 0)
```